# Using DOMDocument, is it possible to get all elements that exists within a certain DOM?

Tags: php, parsing, html-parsing, domdocument

Let's say I have an HTML file with a lot of different elements, each having different attributes. Let's say I do not know beforehand how this HTML will look like.

Using PHP's DOMDocument, how can I iterate over **ALL** elements and modify them? All I see is getElementByTagName and getElementById etc. I want to iterate through all elements.

For instance. Let's say the HTML looks like this (just an example, in reality I do not know the structure):

```
$html = '<div class="potato"><span></span></div>';
```

I want to be able to some simple DOM modification (like in Javascript):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

// Obviously the code below doesn't work but showcases what I want to achieve
foreach($dom->getAllElements as $element ){
    if(!$element->hasClass('potato')){
       $element->addClass('potato');
    } else{
       $element->removeClass('potato');
    }
}
$html = $dom->SaveHTML();
```

So in this instance, I would like the resulting html to look like this:

```
    $html = '<div><span class="potato"></span></div>';
```

So how can I iterate through all elements and do modifications on the fly in an foreach-loop? I really don't want to use regex for this.

Comment: You want to add/invert `class="potato"` to every element?...

Comment: Note that `hasClass` is not available in PHP's DOMNode interface, so you might want to use something that allows CSS selectors, like [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can pass an asterisk `*` with [`getElementsByTagName()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) which returns all elements:

```
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('*') as $element ){

}
```

From the [Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php):

> **name**
>   The local name (without namespace) of the tag to match on. The special value * matches all tags.

Comment: How get with HTML tags for write to new file?